# build pagination items with siblings

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a function that returns me pagination items, and here is what I tried (based on https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/v4.10.2/packages/material-ui-lab/src/Pagination/usePagination.js):

```
const pagination = (totalPages, siblingCount = 2, pageNumber) => {
  const ELLIPSIS = '…';
  const siblingsStart = Math.max(
      Math.min(
        // Natural start
        pageNumber - siblingCount,
        // Lower boundary when page is high
        totalPages - siblingCount * 2 - 2,
      ),
      // Greater than startPage
      3,
    );

    const siblingsEnd = Math.min(
      Math.max(
        // Natural end
        pageNumber + siblingCount,
        // Upper boundary when page is low
        siblingCount * 2 + 3,
      ),
      // Less than endPages
      totalPages - 2,
    );

    // Basic list of items to render
    return [
      1,

      // Start ellipsis
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-nested-ternary
      ...(siblingsStart > 3
        ? [ELLIPSIS]
        : totalPages - 1 > 2
        ? [2]
        : []),

      // Sibling pages
      ...range(siblingsStart, siblingsEnd),

      // End ellipsis
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-nested-ternary
      ...(siblingsEnd < totalPages - 2
        ? [ELLIPSIS]
        : totalPages - 1 > 1
        ? [totalPages - 1]
        : []),

      totalPages,
    ];
};
```

This function will return a string like the following when (for example) `pageNumber = 6` and `totalPages = 20`:

1 … 4 5 6 7 8 … 20

This is working fine, since I want to always display two numbers before and after the `pageNumber`.

So when the `pageNumber = 1` I want the following:

> 1 2 3 … 20

But instead I get this:

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 … 20

The same as when the `pageNumber = 20`, I want to get this:

> 1 … 18 19 20

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are hard-coded lowest, and highest possible sibling pages in the code provided in the question. For example, the code that determines the `siblingsStart` value, which is used to begin the sibling pages—list of pages in the center portion—will never be less than three:

```
const siblingsStart = Math.max( ... , 3); // <-- lowest value returnable is 3
```

So any current page value less than 6, given a value of 2 siblings before the current page, will return `1 2 3 4 5 6 ...`, because the page list always starts with `1`, the `siblingCount` is `2`, and `3` is hard-coded as the lowest sibling page number: `1 + 2 + 3 = 6`.

---

Starting with a blank slate... *first* check to see if current page is close to the first page and if not add first page plus ellipsis to a string. *Next* start looping before the current page and loop the number of sibling pages, making sure not to go before first page, adding each to the string. *After that* start at the current page and loop the sibling count forward, making sure not to go beyond the total pages. And *finally* add the last page if it's not too close to the current page.

```js
const pagination = (pageNumber, totalPages = 40, siblingCount = 2, pageFiller = "…") => {
      pageNumber = parseInt(pageNumber);
      totalPages = parseInt(totalPages);
      let pagination_str = "";

      // add first page if current page is not too close
      if ( 1 < pageNumber - siblingCount ) { 
          pagination_str += "1 ";
          if ( siblingCount + 3 < pageNumber ) { pagination_str += (pageFiller + " "); }
          else if ( siblingCount + 2 < pageNumber ) { pagination_str += "2 "; }
      }

      // get siblingCount before
      for ( 
          // is current page to close to first page?
          let ii = (0 < (pageNumber - siblingCount)? pageNumber - siblingCount: 1); 
          ii < (pageNumber); 
          ii++ 
      ) {
          pagination_str += ii + " ";
      }

      // get siblingCount after
      for ( 
          let ii = pageNumber;
          // is end of increment greater than or equal to the total number of pages?
          ii <= ((totalPages >= pageNumber + siblingCount)? (pageNumber + siblingCount): totalPages); 
          ii++ 
      ) {
          pagination_str += ii + " ";
      }

      // add last page if current page is not too close
      if ( totalPages > pageNumber + siblingCount ) { 
          if ( totalPages - siblingCount - 2 > pageNumber ) { pagination_str += (pageFiller + " "); }
          else if ( totalPages - siblingCount - 1 > pageNumber ) { pagination_str += (totalPages - 1) + " "; }
          pagination_str += totalPages; 
      }
  
      return pagination_str;
};

console.log("page 1 of 7: ", pagination(1, 7));
console.log("page 5 of 7: ", pagination(5, 7));
console.log("page 6 of 7: ", pagination(6, 7));
console.log("page 5 of 20: ", pagination(5, 20));
console.log("page 6 of 20: ", pagination(6, 20));
console.log("page 20 of 20: ", pagination(20, 20));
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, however when I do `pagination(1, 5, 2)` it returns `'1 2 3 … 5'` which is kinda look weird, and for `pagination(4, 5, 2)` as well

Comment: In the case of page = 1, and total pages = 5, do you prefer to see `1 2 3 4 5`? Likewise page = 4, and total pages = 5, the same? In other words if the ellipsis is replacing only one page just put the page...?

Comment: exactly, because the ellipsis has no meaning if it's place between 3 and 5 for example

Comment: @RenaudisNotBillGates Add that additional requirement to your question, so anyone else deciding to take on the challenge know that from the start.