# Paging through hidden divs, pagination fails when clicking page numbers

Tags: javascript, pagination, single-page-application

I have a pagination. But I am having a problem with this pagination as follows.

https://prnt.sc/3DvQ5YlKQB3Q

I want a structure like this 1,...,5,|6|,7,..,20 .

In other words, no matter how many pages there are, at most 7 items should be seen.

My pagination codes that I'm using and my separate function are as follows.

My Javascript Code

```
$(".paginate .items > div").css("display", "none");
$(".paginate .items > div:nth-child(1)").css("display", "block");
$(".paginate .items > div:nth-child(2)").css("display", "block");
var item_count = $(".paginate .items > div").length;
var page = item_count / 2;
var pag_item = pagination(1, page).split(" ");
for (const row of pag_item) {
  if (row == 1) {
    $(".paginate .pager .pageNumbers").append('<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-page="' + row + '" class="active">' + row + '</a>');
  } else {
    $(".paginate .pager .pageNumbers").append('<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-page="' + row + '">' + row + '</a>');
  }
}
if (Math.round(page) <= 1) {
  $(".paginate .pager .pageNumbers").css("display", "none");
}
$(".paginate .pager .pageNumbers").on("click", "a", function() {
  var current_page = $(this).attr("data-page");
  if (current_page != "…") {
    if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
      $(".paginate .pager .pageNumbers").empty();
      pag_item = pagination(current_page, page).split(" ");
      pag_item = pag_item.slice(0, pag_item.length - 1);
      for (const row of pag_item) {
        if (row == current_page) {
          $(".paginate .pager .pageNumbers").append('<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-page="' + row + '" class="active">' + row + '</a>');
        } else {
          $(".paginate .pager .pageNumbers").append('<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-page="' + row + '">' + row + '</a>');
        }
      }
      $(".paginate .items > div").css("display", "none");
      $(".paginate .items > div:nth-child(" + ((current_page * 2) - 1) + ")").css("display", "block");
      $(".paginate .items > div:nth-child(" + (current_page * 2) + ")").css("display", "block");
    }
  }
});
```

[`pagination()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72564432/2743458) function:

```
const pagination = (pageNumber, totalPages = 40, siblingCount = 2) => {
  let pagination_str = "";

  if (1 < pageNumber - siblingCount) {
    pagination_str += "1 ";
    if (siblingCount + 3 < pageNumber) {
      pagination_str += "… ";
    } else if (siblingCount + 2 < pageNumber) {
      pagination_str += "2 ";
    }
  }
  for (
    let ii = (0 < (pageNumber - siblingCount) ? pageNumber - siblingCount : 1); ii < (pageNumber); ii++
  ) {
    pagination_str += ii + " ";
  }
  for (
    let ii = pageNumber; ii <= ((totalPages >= pageNumber + siblingCount) ? (pageNumber + siblingCount) : totalPages); ii++
  ) {
    pagination_str += ii + " ";
  }
  if (totalPages > pageNumber + siblingCount) {
    if (totalPages - siblingCount - 2 > pageNumber) {
      pagination_str += "… ";
    } else if (totalPages - siblingCount - 1 > pageNumber) {
      pagination_str += (totalPages - 1) + " ";
    }
    pagination_str += totalPages;
  }
  return pagination_str;
}
```

Example HTML

```
<div class="paginate">
  <div class="items">
    <div>one</div><div>page one</div><div>two</div><div>page two</div>
    <div>three</div><div>page three</div><div>four</div><div>page four</div>
    <div>five</div><div>page five</div><div>six</div><div>page six</div>
    <div>seven</div><div>page seven</div><div>nine</div><div>page eight</div>
    <div>nine</div><div>page nine</div><div>ten</div><div>page ten</div>
    <div>eleven</div><div>page eleven</div><div>twelve</div><div>page twelve</div>
    <div>thirteen</div><div>page thirteen</div><div>fourteen</div><div>page fourteen</div>
  </div>
  <div class="pager">
    <div class="pageNumbers"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What does your corresponding HTML look like?

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles It's already in the code. I am using append.
https://prnt.sc/Pm6hpd35b_On

Comment: I ran your code, no HTML elements are displayed—blank page. Are you staying on the same page and "paging" through your `div` elements? It helps a bunch to see an example of the HTML code you're working with.

Comment: It took some mental effort to work out the HTML structure you're using. I added sample HTML to your question for you. **Next time you post a question** be sure to give people everything they need to work out a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing a string type page number to the [`pagination()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72564432/2743458) function: `pagination(current_page, page)`. `current_page` is type string.

Without type checks in the `pagination()` function it failed to compare a string page number to an integer page number and returned all pages. [(Source function fixed.)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72564432/2743458)

---

Covering all bases by adding integer type checks to the `pagination()` function, and converting all string page numbers in the `pag_item` array to integers.

Also, using the `pagination()` function `siblingCount` paramater to limit number of page links to 7.

Not chopping off last page: `//pag_item = pag_item.slice(0, pag_item.length - 1);`

And checking for page filler ("...") when appending to page navigation `div`.

```js
const pagination = (pageNumber, totalPages = 40, siblingCount = 2, pageFiller = "…") => {
  // make sure page variables are type integer
  pageNumber = parseInt(pageNumber);
  totalPages = parseInt(totalPages);
  let pagination_str = "";

  // add first page if current page is not too close
  if ( 1 < pageNumber - siblingCount ) { 
    pagination_str += "1 ";
    if ( siblingCount + 3 < pageNumber ) { pagination_str += (pageFiller + " "); }
    else if ( siblingCount + 2 < pageNumber ) { pagination_str += "2 "; }
  }

  // get siblingCount before
  for ( 
    // is current page to close to first page?
    let ii = (0 < (pageNumber - siblingCount)? pageNumber - siblingCount: 1); 
    ii < (pageNumber); 
    ii++ 
  ) {
    pagination_str += ii + " ";
  }

  // get siblingCount after
  for ( 
    let ii = pageNumber;
    // is end of increment greater than or equal to the total number of pages?
    ii <= ((totalPages >= pageNumber + siblingCount)? (pageNumber + siblingCount): totalPages); 
    ii++ 
  ) {
    pagination_str += ii + " ";
  }

  // add last page if current page is not too close
  if ( totalPages > pageNumber + siblingCount ) { 
    if ( totalPages - siblingCount - 2 > pageNumber ) { pagination_str += (pageFiller + " "); }
    else if ( totalPages - siblingCount - 1 > pageNumber ) { pagination_str += (totalPages - 1) + " "; }
    pagination_str += totalPages; 
  }

  return pagination_str;
};

$(".paginate .items > div").css("display", "none");
$(".paginate .items > div:nth-child(1)").css("display", "block");
$(".paginate .items > div:nth-child(2)").css("display", "block");

var item_count = $(".paginate .items > div").length;
var page_count = item_count / 2;

// pagination
// set sibling count to 1 to limit to 7 page links
var pag_item = pagination(1, page_count, 1)
  .split(" ")

  // convert string page number to integers, but not page filler
  .map(pg => "…" === pg? pg: parseInt(pg));

for (const row of pag_item) {
  let active = (row === 1)? "active": "";
  if ( "…" !== row ) { // don't make page filler a link
    $(".paginate .pager .pageNumbers").append('<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-page="' + row + '" class="' + active + '">' + row + '</a>');
  }
  else { $(".paginate .pager .pageNumbers").append(row); }

}

$(".paginate .pager .pageNumbers").on("click", "a", function() {
  var current_page = $(this).attr("data-page");
  if (current_page !== "…") {
    if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
      $(".paginate .pager .pageNumbers").empty();

      // pagination
      // set sibling count to 1 to limit to 7 page links
      pag_item = pagination(current_page, page_count, 1).split(" ");

      // why chop off last page??
      //pag_item = pag_item.slice(0, pag_item.length - 1);
      for (const row of pag_item) {
        let active = (row === current_page)? "active": "";
        if ( "…" !== row ) { // don't make page filler a link
          $(".paginate .pager .pageNumbers").append('<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-page="' + row + '" class="' + active + '">' + row + '</a>');
        }
                else { $(".paginate .pager .pageNumbers").append(row); }
      }
      $(".paginate .items > div").css("display", "none");
      $(".paginate .items > div:nth-child(" + ((current_page * 2) - 1) + ")").css("display", "block");
      $(".paginate .items > div:nth-child(" + (current_page * 2) + ")").css("display", "block");
    }
  }
});
```

```css
a {
  padding: .1em;
}

.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="paginate">
  <div class="items">
    <div>one</div><div>page one</div><div>two</div><div>page two</div>
    <div>three</div><div>page three</div><div>four</div><div>page four</div>
    <div>five</div><div>page five</div><div>six</div><div>page six</div>
    <div>seven</div><div>page seven</div><div>nine</div><div>page eight</div>
    <div>nine</div><div>page nine</div><div>ten</div><div>page ten</div>
    <div>eleven</div><div>page eleven</div><div>twelve</div><div>page twelve</div>
    <div>thirteen</div><div>page thirteen</div><div>fourteen</div><div>page fourteen</div>
  </div>
  <div class="pager">
    <div class="pageNumbers"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```